# Application.Run executes in new desktop but dont runs form

Tags: c#

i created an preview form (form1.cs) with an button, the click event of the button is to run ChatForm.cs. ChatForm.cs is designed with GunaFramework and has actually no code, only design.

The desktop is creating, but the new Form is not running.
I tried to make an new Form without any controls (only a WinForms textBox) and this works.
So is the error caused at Gunaframework or does i have an bug in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many UI components will assume that there is a single UI thread (some explicitly, some not), and many problems become *much* more difficult to solve when you have multiple UI threads.  You're really going to be better off using a single UI thread.  The fact that you're blocking one of the UI threads on the other also indicates there is no *reason* for you to have multiple UI threads either.  You should just have the one.

Comment: So this means if i would use in the mainform also only Guna-controls i should have only 1 UI thread? Or did you mean if. Because i have only a single Guna Thread because the main form is´nt designed with Guna

Comment: You should only have one UI thread always in *all* situations.  The fact is that many libraries often rely on there only being one UI thread (which may or may not be the case here, I'm not familiar with this particular library, but it appears to be the case given what you've described).

Comment: Alright and what could i do to fix this problem? Should i also contact GunaFramework?

Comment: You should use a single UI thread.  Just like I said in my last two comments.

Comment: Yeah, but how should i do this? I must be able to run this new form with gunaframework, so i should kill the main UI - Thread?

Comment: Why would you need to kill the existing UI thread?   You just use the existing UI thread for *all* UI elements.

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem. You have problem X and attempted solution Y ( multiple UI threads). As @Servy mentions, your proposed solution is probably not the correct approach, but since you do not specify X it is impossible to suggest the correct approach. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yes but this seems to be not possible if i need this form in the new desktop, or i´m wrong?

Comment: @JonasH the difference between multiple UI threads and this is that i want to run it in a freshly created dekstop, and i if close this new created form, the new desktop should also close and the mainform still running.

Comment: Are you talking about the virtual desktop feature in windows? Because it is explicitly not the intent to allow programs to scatter windows over multiple virtual desktop. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201123-00/?p=104476

Comment: No i dont think that that the point is, because when it should be what you linked, why this should work with WinForm-Controls form and not with GunaFramework-Controls?

Comment: @Paul You're being told that what you're trying to do is not a good idea and you should not do it.  You keep asking why a given library doesn't let you do something that's a bad idea while another one does, and what you should be asking is *what you should actually be doing*.

Comment: Are you using multiple UI threads?